Error message on boot: Dependency failed for sssd-pam-pri... Service responder private socket
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-pam-pri... Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-pam.soc... SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-ssh.soc... SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-sudo.so... SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.

Hello community,
So when I put on my computer, automatically  I got this error.

Details needed. What version and type of Ubuntu? Has it ever worked? Please edit the question and add the info.
